# Filter pandas dataframe with varying number of conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of columns that act as filtering conditions in a pandas df, but the list has a varying number of columns and I would like a way to automate the filtering with all columns without having to specify them individually.

Here's what the code looks like:

```
filters = ['col_43', 'col_44', 'col_45', ...]

filtered_df = df[(df[filters[0]]=='Y') | (df[filters[1]]=='Y') | (df[filters[2]]=='Y')...]
```

Sometimes the list could contain 10 filters, other times more. Is automation possible?

I'm using pandas 1.0.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have the same condition for all columns, use [`any`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) and [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
filtered_df = df[df[filters].eq('Y').any(axis=1)]
```

If you want to use different conditions, you would need a dictionary:

```
filters = {'col_43': 'Y', 'col_44': 'N'}

filtered_df = df[df[list(filters)].eq(filters).all(axis=1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, automation is possible using the **any()** function and list comprehension in Python. You can modify your code to dynamically apply the filtering conditions based on the varying number of columns in the filters list. Here's an example:

```
filters = ['col_43', 'col_44', 'col_45', ...]
filtered_df = df[(df[filters].eq('Y')).any(axis=1)]
```

**df[filters].eq('Y')** creates a boolean DataFrame where each column specified in filters is compared to the value **'Y'**. The result is a DataFrame with True values where the condition is met and False values otherwise.

Then, by applying the any(axis=1) method on this DataFrame, it checks if any of the columns have a True value for each row. This returns a boolean Series indicating whether any of the conditions are satisfied for each row.